# Get creation and last modified date from a PAR file created in Solid Edge

Tags: file, siemens, siemens-nx

I do not have Solid Edge installed, but I need to get internal creation and modification dates from the file.
Not Windows/Linux last edited/created dates, but internal, as system-controlled dates get overwritten after downloading a file from the internet.
Is it possible to parse the creation date from the raw file itself?
Preferably without installing Solid Edge.
On the computer that does have Solid Edge, Windows explorer has a "Datum" property, that shows old dates, but on my PC it has no property that would show those dates.